# Cannot Hide Or Make Private My Page's Post

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make my page's post *private* with the following code:

```
var postParams = new { privacy = new { value = "SELF", description = "Private" } };

var c1 = new FacebookClient("my_user_access_token");

var resp1 = c1.Post("/v2.12/my_post_id", postParams);
```

However, I receive the following response (which is not very descriptive):

> (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Failed to edit object

I have also tried simply marking the post as "hidden" but I receive the following error:

```
var postParams = new { is_hidden = "true" };
```

> (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Cannot hide/unhide story posted by page itself

Lastly, I tried using the page's access token to perform the action but I receive the same error.

**How can I update the privacy or hide my page's posts?**

Is the only way do this actually by *deleting* it?

The documentation says (1), **"An app can update a post only if it was the one that published it."**  My updates are published via a different application. I suppose that's the problem - but it seems odd that I can delete but not edit! If it belong to me, then I should have permission to do with it as I please, no?

References:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post#updating

Comment: _Page_ posts do not have a `privacy` field - that is for posts on _user_ timelines.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  So, deletion is the only way, I presume?

Comment: Well you could try if you can hide it via `targeting` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/feed - not sure though whether that allows to specify an “audience of none”, you’ll have to check.

Comment: It looks like that just supports geo_locations and locales.  Thanks, again.  I'll just delete them!